# #1932 - Table '' doesn't exist in engine after accidental delete

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I forgot to export my main table before deleting and reinstalling xampp. I recovered it from the recycling bin, but I get #1932 - Table '' doesn't exist in engine when I try to open any of the tables. Collation for each table says "in use". Is there anyway to fix this mistake?

Comment: Assuming that the table is InnoDB one and innodb_file_per_table is enabled: store recovered tablespace file, create empty table with the same name and structure (strict matching needed!), drop its tablespace, replace empty tablespace file with one saved before and import tablespace.